# Playing sound on mouseover

Tags: javascript

Here is a link to my code: http://jsbin.com/ebadic/1/edit

It is from a demo I found here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/jamwithchrome-interaction/

It creates 6 guitar strings. What I would like to do is have a sound play when one of the 6 strings is moused over - A different sound for each string, or a single sound that is pitched up/down for each string

My code already plays a sound when I mouseover a single string, but the problem is that it plays the same sound for each one. How do I make it play a DIFFERENT SOUND for each string?

Comment: That is a lot of code. Perhaps it would help if you tided it up a bit - like put the css in the css panel... etc.

It may also help if you could provide a slimmed down version of your code that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have predefined soundfiles it could work this way:

```
//Javascript:
function playSound( url ){   document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML="<embed src='"+url+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";}
```